# IsEnabled Binding performance concerns?

Tags: performance, binding

I am dynamically loading around 1000+ items which are translated to buttons in xaml.

The view model has an IsEnabled property that is binded to the IsEnabled property of the button in the View.

My question is, won't this affect performance? I only need the property on some of the items but all of them use the same viewmodel and it is quite hard to introduce a new view model just for that purpose.

I am using Windows Store 8.1.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1k bool bindings should not do any harm. I've seen applications with 5-10k bindings beeing populated at once, they can freeze a little bit if done in sync. Your item/list in viewmodel loading should be done async to avoid UI freeze if the collection of those items is bound instantly with all the items already there, that is why observable collection is a fundamental thing to bind to.